# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = ab$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

alright so I have to assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=b$ 
And then I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \ b_n=ab$ by using the definition of convergence of sequences.

Any tips/solutions thanks guys.

Comment: Could you use LaTeX to format your question? It's very ambiguous   at the moment

Comment: Can you show the work you've done so far? Maybe start with the definition of convergence?

Comment: There is too much to fix. Learn \latex, then fix your mistakes.

Comment: the limit of a sequence = the definition of convergence of sequences :P

Comment: @gger234 Perhaps start by writing down the *formal* definition of a limit: It should involve an $\epsilon$ and and $N$.

Comment: and then n>=N then |an-L| < epsilon :O

Comment: @gger234 we don't want to seem unfriendly, but you have to realize that people will be less likely to help if you don't seem like you've tried at all. You should at least be able to write down the definition - your comment was just a sentence fragment. As others have mentioned, it helps if you can use latex, the language for displaying mathematics.

Comment: well, then again i could just compy paste the defintion from the book, but well I will keep it in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write both definitions: let $\epsilon>0$ and let us fix $0\le r\le1$ (small) to be chosen later.
Then there is $N$ such as 
$$
n\ge N\implies
\max(|a_n-a| ,|b_n-b|)<r
\\
\implies |a_n|\le |a|+r
$$Let us write
$$
a_nb_n-ab=a_n(b_n-b)+(a_n-a)b 
$$Then use the definition and the triangle inequality:
$$
|a_nb_n-ab|\le
|a_n||b_n-b|+|a_n-a||b| \le (|a|+r)r + |b|r\le |a|r + |b|r +r
$$

Now chose $r$ such as 
$$
0<(|a|+|b|+1)r\le\epsilon\\
$$
we can choose for example:
$$
r = \frac \epsilon{|a|+|b|+1}>0
$$
Then
$$
|a_nb_n-ab|\le (|a|+|b|)r \le \epsilon
$$

Comment: oh wow. thats damn impressive? r is basically epsilon isnt it? and s=delta? idk :)

Comment: yes I edited with traditionnal names :) \epsilon is damn long to write ;)

Comment: but what about r? I've never seen that before?

Comment: @gger234: Roger Godement use the $r$ in his book (a great book by the way), but is not very common.

Comment: @gger234 you can basically use any letter ;)

Comment: well, whats up s in the bottom line? where did it come from? the s I mean, just randomly shows up`?

Comment: there is still a random "s" in the bottom line?

Comment: yep, this was the last one. I also fixed a potential error (divide by 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is other approach (a little different than the usual): We proof  two special cases which are almost trivial and makes the general case easier to handle:

1. If $c_n \to c$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$ so $kc_n \to kc$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|c_n-c|<\varepsilon/(|k|+1)$ for all $n\ge n_0$. So $$|kc_n-kc|=|k||c_n-c|< \varepsilon$$
2. If $c_n \to c$ and $d_n \to d$, then $(c_n-c)(d_n-d)\to 0$. Given $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|c_n-c|< \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ and $|d_n-d|<\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Hence $$|(c_n-c)(d_n-d)|=|c_n-c||d_n-d|< \varepsilon$$

For the general case (I suppose you've already proven the sum rule):

\begin{align}\lim_n (a_nb_n-ab)=\lim_n\big[(a_n-a)(b_n-b)+b(a_n-a)+a(b_n-b)\big]\\
=\lim_n(a_n-a)(b_n-b)+b\lim_n(a_n-a)+a\lim_n(b_n-b)\\
=0+b\cdot 0+a\cdot 0=0\end{align}

and thus $\lim_n a_nb_n - ab=0$, which is equivalent to $\lim_n a_nb_n = ab$

as was to be shown.